# Remove Settings Manager from bottom of Whisker Menu

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, xfce, xfce-panel, whisker

The upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 Xubuntu has caused this "Settings Manager" icon to appear at the bottom of my Whsiker Menu. How can I remove it? I've removed its category that marks it as a "top level" Xfce icon, but even after a reboot this has seemingly done absolutely nothing.

[image]

Comment: In the Whisker settings, there's a bunch of checkboxes controlling those buttons.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Feel free to post that as an answer. The specific menu is "Properties" -> "Commands". Incidentally, I think that "I can never guess where any given setting is" is my biggest issue with XFCE.